# What is the meaning of delta squared?

Tags: titration

I know that $\Delta x = x_2 - x_1$. This is well known
Therefore, it follows that $\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}$ = $\frac{a_2 - a_1}{b_2 - b_1}$ (Unless I missed an elementary math class!)

Now, I found an equation in chemistry, while reading, that turns this principle on its head. It proposes that when considering the second in a set of values:
$\frac{\Delta^2 a}{\Delta b^2} = (a_3 - a_2) \times \frac{1}{\Delta b}$

My issue with this is that $a_3$ hasn't been measured yet, we have only $a_1$ and $a_2$ so how can this be?

Secondly, they propose this:
$\frac{\Delta \left(\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b}\right)}{\Delta b} = \frac{\Delta^2 a}{\Delta b^2}$

Can anyone please help with the logic behind the first equation and algebra behind the second one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hate to break it you, but they're hiding the math from you that is really going on behind the scenes.

It is very common in situations where the students are not expected to know calculus, that wherever a derivative would be needed, to replace, for example, the $dx$ with a $\Delta x$. This is because for many simple physical systems, taking the derivative results in simply measuring the average change in a property with respect to some other property.

For instance, consider a system where you know the position of some particle and how this position changes with time. If you want to know the velocity of that particle at any given time, you would take the derivative with respect to time, $$v=\frac{dx}{dt}$$but, in many cases you might be only interested in the **average velocity** and could thus skip the derivative part and write that $$v=\frac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}=\frac{x_2-x_1}{t_2-t_1}$$

But, and now we're getting to your question, let's take it one step further and say we wanted to know the acceleration of that particle. This would be the derivative of velocity which is also written as the **second derivative** of position with respect to time. Thus, we would write $$a=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$Notice how similar this looks to your question about $\Delta^2$ if you simply replace the $d$ with $\Delta$.

Again, if we decided we were only interested in the **average acceleration**, then we would write $$a=\frac{\Delta^2 x}{\Delta t}$$
The reason why they say that $$\frac{\Delta(\frac{\Delta a}{\Delta b})}{\Delta b}=\frac{\Delta^2 a}{\Delta b^2}$$is again because that is true of derivatives. This would be written as $$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dx}{dt})=\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=a$$

So, to summarize, the symbol $\Delta$ is often used in situations where you care about a change from one state to another (as with a change in energy) or when you only care about the average of some quantity.

As to why they are able to write$$\frac{\Delta^2 a}{\Delta b^2}=\frac{a_3-a_2}{\Delta b}$$ I'm not certain about. I would have to know what this dealt with specifically. My guess is that the quantity $a_3$ is somehow related to the second derivative of $a$ with respect to $b$ and they did some algebra behind the scenes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your exceedingly easy to understand explanation. This is a bit embarrassing because I do know calculus, however, taking the $\Delta$ symbol to mean "change in " it was only natural for me to want to divide the numerator by $\Delta b^2$. If the textbook had explained the substitution or that differentiating was at the heart of this, I'd have gotten it right away. Thank you ever so kindly